# Data Access Layer for Android

Tags: java, android, data-access-layer

Im currently trying to build my first android app and its a learning curve (I will overcome!) seeing as I have come from a .net C#/vb.net web background (no java background)

I worked through the Notepad example that google provide and now working on my own app which has three tables in the sqlite database.

I'm having to build a method for each insert, delete, edit etc and then more for reading the database.

I was curious to see if their are any nice Dataaccess layers out there that help with this (I've grown a custom to fluent NHibernate and using linq)

It seems a lot of work to be writing all this sql inside the java files!

Comment: If You have experience with ORM (NHibernate?) then You can try ORMLite http://ormlite.com/